# powershell pass variables throw try/catch

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use try / catch with the if statement to verify that a directory exists **(I hope this is a correct solution!?)**, but I have a problem setting and passing the value of the $RepoDir variable into the catch statement

```
try {

    if (Notexists -Path $RepoDoc) {
       $RepoDir = "a"
       -ErrorAction Stop
    } 
    if (Notexists -Path $RepoExcel) {
       $RepoDir = "b"
       -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    if (Notexists -Path $RepoAttach) {
       $RepoDir = "c"
       -ErrorAction Stop
    }
}
catch {
   Write-Host "Directory $RepoDir not exist !" ---> Directory not exist ! 
   break
}
```

Is it a scope problem?
How could I do that?
Thank you

Comment: You can pass the variable by just defining it before your try/catch block. Maybe I don't see the issue because of lack of context.

Comment: Is this the ACTUAL code!?

Comment: @marsze - Yes this is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proper way of doing what you want would be something like this:

```
$RepoDoc, $RepoExcel, $RepoAttach | Where-Object {
    -not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $_)
} | ForEach-Object {
    "Directory ${_} does not exist."
}
```

Comment: @Gus Then one of the variables you're feeding into the pipeline is empty.

Comment: @Ansarg - It makes sense to put your script in a try / catch ? How? Thanks

Comment: and how can I use it for check files exist? Thanks

Comment: @Gus No, it does not make sense to put the code in a `try..catch`. And since you need to ask how to check for the presence of a file when presented with code that checks for their absence, you are clearly in way over your head. Please go find a PowerShell tutorial and learn the basics first.

Comment: Thanks for your solution - that's what I was looking for